# How to get data from a Controller when refreshing the page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a dashboard where i need to update the notifications bar each time i refresh the page so that, when refreshing the page, the controller has to be executed and it will return data from the database to that page.

What is the best way to do this? I've tried some stuff with the onload event but i cant seem to find a way of getting into the controller with it

Currently im trying:
Jquery/Ajax:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'<?=base_url('notificacoes') ?>'
   }).done(function(e){
    console.log(e);
    $('#notbadge').html(e);
   }) 
});
```

Controller:

```
<?php

    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Notificacoes extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Notificacoes', '', TRUE);
            $this->load->model('Viatura', '', TRUE);
            $this->load->library('session');
        }

        public function index(){
            $matricula = $this->session->viatura;
            $viatura = $this->Viatura_model->read($matricula);

            return $viatura;

        }
    }
```

HTML badge:

```
<span class="badge" id="notbadge"></span>
```

It doesn't print me the array on the console, why?

Comment: Can you post a code example and the things that you have tried alread?

Comment: Updated, please check

Answer (score 1):

To get notification refereshing a page each time is not a good idea you should use javascript or angular js for this. try something like this.

```
$scope.getNotifications = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . "dashboard/getNotifications" ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //console.log(data);
                $scope.notifications = data;
                $scope.total_unread_noti = data.total_unread_noti;
                $scope.$apply();
            }

        });
    };
    $scope.getNotifications();


    setInterval(function () {
        $scope.getNotifications();
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain the ajax code your using? im not familiar with ajax